# Angular 2(2.4.10) and Kendo-angular-grid(0.22.3) does not compile with Webpack and AOT

Tags: angular, webpack, kendo-grid

I am new to this kendo UI and angular 2. While trying to make a production build of my angular 2 application using kendo-angular-grid(0.22.3) with webpack and AOT,it is throwing a compilation error.

> npm run ngc && npm run webpack-production
>   asp.net@1.0.0 ngc C:\Users..\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects..\testwebapp> ngc -p ./tsconfig-aot.json
>   Error at C:/Users/../Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/../testwebapp/Scripts/App/item-list.component.ngfactory.ts:24:27: **Cannot find module '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/grid.component.ngfactory'**.
>   Error at C:/Users/../Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/../testwebapp/Scripts/App/item-list.component.ngfactory.ts:28:27: **Cannot find module '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/column.component.ngfactory**'.

The problem is loader is not looking into the proper folder. I have this in my webpack.prod.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var path = require('path');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = {
devtool: 'source-map',
entry: {
    'polyfills': './Scripts/polyfills.ts',
    'app': './Scripts/main-aot.ts'
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.ts', '.js']
},
output: {

    path: path.join(__dirname, '.dist/web/aot/'),
    filename: 'js/[name]-[hash:8].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[id]-[hash:8].chunk.js'
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: [
                'awesome-typescript-loader',
                'angular-router-loader?aot=true&genDir=Scripts/.aot/'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: 'raw-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]',
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader')
        }
    ],
    exprContextCritical: false
},


plugins: [

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['app', 'polyfills']
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        options: {
            htmlLoader: {
                minimize: false
            }
        }
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({

        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body',
        template: './Scripts/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false,
            drop_console: true
        },
        output: {
            comments: false
        }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
        }
    })
]
```

};

Comment: I figured it out. The path was missing in the config. The full configuration is

Comment: Answer you own question @suman